# Windows 8 app search - whole word only?

Tags: windows-8

When I first started using Windows 8, I swear that typing "snip" from the start screen would give the Snipping Tool as a result. Now, I have to type "Snipping" before I get a result. I guess I can do "snip*", but is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Click `View`
3. Click `Options`
4. Click the `Search` tab
5. Check `Find partial matches`

Comment: Thank you. It's possible I changed that (though through some other mechanism than that dialog) when actually searching for files in Windows Explorer. I didn't realize they used the same rules. That's unfortunate because when finding apps I want to be lenient but when I'm trying to find a specific file I do not want a ton of useless results.

Comment: Looks like in Windows 10, this no-longer exists.